# Android Can't Call Background Task onDestroy

Tags: android, background, ondestroy

I run this background task throughout my app, but when calling it onDestory it does not seem to work..

```
public void onDestroy()

{


    BackgroundTask backgroundTaskLogin = new BackgroundTask(MainActivity.this);
    backgroundTaskLogin.execute(task, phone, "Stuff", database);


}
```

What it does (should do ) is access a database.

Comment: onDestroy must be @override

Comment: I can access variables and such and when System.out.println("test"); I can see it when app exits.. So it working fine, just will not call background task...

Comment: You are probrably creating a memory leak... You should start a service or a intent service to perform this action. If you class holds a reference to you MainActivity, the gc will not collect It until the task is finished